# Orderby Numeric Colunm

Tags: sql-server

```
 J12M1
 J12M14
 J12M15
 J12M18
 J12M2
 J12M21
 J12M22
 J12M23
 J12M24
 J12M25
 J12M26
 J12M27
 J12M28
 J12M29
 J12M35
 J12M36
 J12M39
```

but my need is

```
 J12M1
 J12M2
 J12M3
```

What can I do in my query

```
select productnumber from vt_fe_product order by productnumber
```

Comment: Where does `J12M3` in the second list come from? It's not in your first list.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend with zeros:

```
SELECT 
   productnumber 
FROM   
   vt_fe_product 
ORDER BY 
   Right( '0000000000' + productnumber, 10 )
```

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3326371/284240)

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d822d/3/0)

Result:

```
PRODUCTNUMBER
J12M1
J12M2
J12M14
J12M15
J12M18
J12M21
J12M22
J12M23
J12M24
J12M25
J12M26
J12M27
J12M28
J12M29
J12M35
J12M36
J12M39
```

Comment: +1 I have not seen that trick before.

Comment: @bluefeet: Me neither! Learned it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3326371/284240).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need try to use additional LEN function?

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM
(
 SELECT 
 'J12M1' AS ProductName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M14' AS ProductName
 .......................
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M24' AS ProductName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M25' AS ProductName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M35' AS ProductName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M36' AS ProductName
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 'J12M39' AS ProductName
) AS Products
ORDER BY LEN(ProductName), ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

If your productnumber format is well-defined (i.e. it will always be 'J12M' followed by a number), then you can remove the 'fixed' part and cast the numeric part for your sort. Something along the lines of:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, REPLACE(productnumber, 'J12M', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order this way:-

`select product_number
from vtfe_product 
order by CONVERT(int, substring(product_number, 5, len(product_number) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Already seen the other answers.  Decided to take a different route.  Bit more verbose, but the nice thing about this solution is that you end up sorting on actual numbers, and it sorts on the 'J' number first.

```
SELECT 
    -- Get the first numeric component
    CAST (
        SUBSTRING(
            productnumber, 
            CHARINDEX('J', productnumber, 1) + 1, 
            CHARINDEX('M', productnumber, 1) - CHARINDEX('J',productnumber, 1) - 1)
        AS INT 
    ) AS FirstSort,
    -- Get the second numeric component
    CAST (
        SUBSTRING(
            productnumber, CHARINDEX('M', productnumber, 1) + 1, LEN(productnumber))
        AS INT
    ) AS SecondSort,
    productnumber
FROM
    productnumbers
ORDER BY
    FirstSort,
    SecondSort
```

DEMO

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd371/2